# Queryable.Any() returning null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database lookup like:

```
var configs = dbData.Configs.Where(e => headers.Contains(e.headerId) && e.flag == "true");
if(configs.Any())
{ ... }
```

where configs is returned as an IQueryable type.  I sometimes get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The cast to value type 'Boolean'
>   failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result
>   type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32
>   ordinal) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper) at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

It happens in production, seemingly randomly and I haven't been able to reproduce it in development.

EDIT TO ADD:  The Config type has a foreign key constraint, if the Boolean type is being cast from that, I don't know.  There is no Boolean in the Config type created by Entity Framework and there is no Boolean type in Sql Server anyway.

Comment: if you want to reproduce it, try reproducing it when you would expect configs to have not results

Comment: Are there always *some* configs, any they just might not match the criteria? Or might `dbData.Configs` be entirely empty?

Comment: what is `headers` how big can it be and which version of entity framework?

Comment: Any() is trying to evaluate your expression, but if there are no records it fails.  Try using if (configs.Count() > 0) instead of Any()

Comment: @Mangist wouldn't `Count()` also evaluate the expression?

Comment: @Mangist, if there is no records, Any() will return false, not an exception ;-)

Comment: @Mangist If there are no records it doesn't fail, it returns `false` because there are no items.  It is exactly the right tool for the job, and is superior to using `Count` as it can short circuit as soon as it finds a single item.

Comment: What is the type of e.flag?  Is it a string or a bool?  If it's a bool try  && ((bool?)e.flag ?? false).  I've seen this error before when there are nullable types in the expression.

Comment: @Mangist If that were the problem it wouldn't result in the error given here, it would result in a different error message.

Comment: I have tried with the same data and input as in production.  It is EF5, and Mangist is correct, it corrctly returns false on an empty set and e.flag is a varchar, not a bool.

Comment: Check that your EF model is consistent with your database schema.  If you haven't done an "update model from database" on your edmx file, the generated classes may not match what you're using in your query.  So the e.HeaderId or e.Flag properties may not be nullable when they should be.  Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Are you sure that your actual code is correctly represented in the question? Do you get the same error if you move the expression out of the `Where` and re-write the `if` as `if(dbData.Configs.Any(e => headers.Contains(e.headerId) && e.flag == "true"))`?

Comment: @SteveRuble I'm still trying to nail down exactly what data is causing the error since it is not repeatable.  There seem to be some initial conditions that need to exist in the database for the error to occur.  I did find that the IQueryable creates a copy of the Any() function and and re-casts the data (presumably as Enumerable<Config> type).  This is where I think the error is coming from.  IEnumerable.Any() does not do this.  I think I can fix it by forcing the query to return an Enumerable<Config>, but I'd still like to know the cause.

Comment: @Mangist I checked the type definition in the designer.cs file.  It looks legit.  I don't want to fix it yet until I can repeat the error reliably, but that is something I will try.

Comment: @DeeArgee, can `e.headerId` be null?

Comment: @SteveRuble technically yes according to the entity model, but since it is a foreign key constraint in the database, it never is.

Comment: @DeeArgee, hmm, what about e.flag?

Comment: @SteveRuble e.flag is a string and yes it is nullable.

Comment: I suggest that you check the query generated by `configs.Any()` with a SQL profiler and perhaps post it here.

Comment: @Slauma I used ToTraceString() on the dbData.Configs.Where(...) query, but that won't work on the Any() function.  Is there another way?

Comment: "SQL Server Profiler": it's a tool that is installed with SQL Server (at least for certain versions, I believe all non-Express versions and for SQL Server Express 2012 and later). The tool captures the traffic to and from SQL Server and can show the actual queries that are executed.

Answer (score 2):

You have some database column in your Configs table that has a nullable boolean type, but the C# entity you are mapping the table entry to is defined as using a non-nullable boolean.  When the C# entity is being populated by the query provider, when it runs into a `null` value, it throws this exception.  You need to update the entity object so that the column in question is of the proper type.

Comment: Hmm... but wouldn't that just result in `Any` returning 0?

Comment: @AndrewBarber No.  In the course of the implementation of `Any` it tries to get the first item in the result set.  If it can get that item successfully it returns `true`.  If it successfully determines that there is no item then it returns `false`.  If there is an error in getting the first item, which is what happened, `Any` propagates that error.  Could they have implemented it differently, sure, is it wrong to implement it like this, I wouldn't say so.  He needs to fix this problem eventually anyway.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think if it can't map the entity types then it fails immediately; it doesn't get as far as trying to evaulate `Any()`. Also, `Any()` returns `bool`, so it can't return 0.

Comment: this kind of query, under EF6, will not use columns names in the generated SQL (select) so if the `Config` object use bool while there is a column bool? in the table, it wouldn't matter

Comment: @Fredou Well, the error message indicates that that's exactly what's happening.  Perhaps the OP is using a different query provider than you are.

Comment: This is not the case.  All the columns are either varchar or int.  A

Comment: @DeeArgee Well your entity clearly has a boolean property, or so the error message claims.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory, based on the fact that `e.flag` is a nullable column: I think that you're getting this error when `e.flag` is null, because the `null` value propagates through your predicate and makes it end up being null on the SQL side, even though at compile time the types of the C# expression is `bool` not `bool?`. When EF tries to materialize the value it throws.

If I'm right, changing the predicate to the following will fix it:

```
var configs = dbData.Configs.Where(e => headers.Contains(e.headerId) && (e.flag ?? "") == "true");
```

Comment: I tried setting flag to null in the database, but still haven't been able to trigger the error.  I will do more testing along this line though.  Only a software engineer would say "It would be awesome if I can make this thing fail."