# "The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null" when nothing is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this line

```
if (EF.ctx.Searches.Any(x => x.SearchTerm == _searchTerm && x.IpAddress == ip && x.Time > dtRecent))
```

throwing this error randomly (rarely, non-reproducible)

> The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

In the database, only IpAddress is nullable (but so far there is no record with null IpAddress).
Everytime the error was thrown, none of the variables were null.

The closest similar question is [Queryable.Any() returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246178/queryable-any-returning-null)
But this error still doesn't make sense to me.

I am really curious, what on earth can be **null** in that line?

Stacktrace:

> at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
>       at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
>       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
>       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
>       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
>       at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>       at [my code, the line above]

Comment: When you say 'non reproducible', are you re-testing with the database, same parameters, etc? If yes, can you profile the database and perform some stress test to attempt to force this to happen? That might be your best chance.

Comment: it's hard to believe `Any` could throw some exception here. It should be translated to some sql query (using `EXISTS`) and the result of materialization here is just a `bool` converted from `bit`. The SQL query should always return `0` or `1`. But somehow the materialization cannot be done. You can check the generated sql query (although I don't think it may involve - it should just be fine to execute against db directly and returns a bit 0 or 1).

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Yes, in the catch block, I reevaluate the expression with the exact same parameters, it doesn't throw the exception a second time. I have tried a loop evaluating the same expression that failed, 1000s of time, haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue, from my own observations I get this issue when selecting the results into a custom class. If I replicate the same thing but with a dynamic cast (new { blah = blah...}) then I get the same error but for 'cast to type Int32'. My problem is what ever parameter is buried in a load of others and I don't know which one it is.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was like databasehas some changes so we cleaned some tables and that is it.

I mean the advice is to revise your database.